# How to limit number of records in a non-generic IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

When I have an `IQueryable<T>` (generic) I can use the `Take` method to return only N records from the result set returned by the query.

When I'm using a simple non-generic `IQueryable`, `Take` method is not available. Is there an other way to achieve the same result as the `Take` method?

**UPDATE:** as Richard pointed, another question solves this problem. In my case, the necessary code was even simpler then the code proposed by Jon Skeet in the other question. That's my final code:

```
dynamic tempQuery = originalQuery;
finalQuery = Queryable.Take(tempQuery, numRecords);
```

Comment: Why do you use non-generic version? Extension methods works only for generic one.

Comment: Jon Skeet answered the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285598/iqueryable-non-generic-missing-count-and-skip-it-works-with-iqueryablet

Comment: For architecture reasons, all I have in this point of code is the non-generic IQueryable. The question linked by Richard was useful, so I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this extension method:

```
public static IQueryable Take(this IQueryable source, int count)
{
    MethodCallExpression mce = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable),
        "Take",
        new Type[] { source.ElementType },
        source.Expression,
        Expression.Constant(count)
    );
    return source.Provider.CreateQuery(mce);
}
```

You can achieve a similar effect with the various extension methods defined on `Queryable` like `Skip` and others, provided you match the method signatures and provide well-formed expression trees.